# Firefox does not display the result xml when converting it to another xml using xslt

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt

I have this xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
  <product id="p1" name="Delta" price="3250" stock="4" country="Denmark"/>
  <product id="p2" name="Golf" price="1000" stock="5" country="Germany"/>
  <product id="p3" name="Alpha" price="1200" stock="19" country="Germany"/>
  <product id="p4" name="Foxtrot" price="1500" stock="5" country="Australia"/>
  <product id="p5" name="Tango" price="1225" stock="3" country="Japan"/>
</products>
```

I want to group it depending on "country" by using xslt stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <products>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="products/product" group-by="@country">
        <xsl:comment>
          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </products>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to see the results on Firefox, and the result I currently get is:

Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT transformation failed.

Instead of the desired result, my question is why does firefox not display the correct result?

Comment: I don't think Firefox supports XSLT 2.0. Try XSLT 1.0 (convert the `<xsl:for-each-group>` to Muenchian grouping).

Comment: @Tomalak What browsers, if any, support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: That's a very interesting question. You should do some research on it. :)

Comment: @user3786761 "*What browsers, if any, support XSLT 2.0?*" AFAIK, none. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#Processor_implementations

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 2.0 in the browser then http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml is an option. There are no browsers with built-in support.